# bolt errors in the neo4j driver

Tags: go, neo4j

I have trouble to play with the Neo4j library, I get an error when I try to debug my Go application, the error is connected to the neo4j connector.
This is the error:

```
github.com/neo4j-drivers/gobolt
../../neo4j-drivers/gobolt/connector.go:199:20: could not determine kind of name for C.BOLT_MODE_DIRECT
../../neo4j-drivers/gobolt/connector.go:201:10: could not determine kind of name for C.BOLT_MODE_ROUTING
../../neo4j-drivers/gobolt/connector.go:227:2: could not determine kind of name for C.BoltConfig_set_mode
../../neo4j-drivers/gobolt/connector.go:227:33: could not determine kind of name for C.BoltMode
```

Can anyone help me with that?
Thanks

Comment: please share any relevant code with us

Comment: Have you checked the requirements? https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-go-driver

Comment: I installed the requirements but I guess it is something about that, I use Fedora and I think there is something that I miss in the requirements.
```
driver, err := neo4j.NewDriver("bolt://localhost:7687", neo4j.BasicAuth("neo4j", "", ""))
 if err != nil {
  le.WithError(err).Fatal("couldn't possible connect to neo4j")
 }

 neoSession, err := driver.Session(neo4j.AccessModeWrite)
 if err != nil {
  le.WithError(err).Fatal("couldn't possible get neo4j neoSession")
 }
 defer neoSession.Close()
```
The code is that but the problem is before